# Capture linux VM in Azure NEW portal

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine

I'm new to Azure (been working on ESXi, AWS and Google Cloud)
due to a specific needs.

I didn't knew till a few minutes ago that there is the new and old portals
and apparently VMs on the new portal (that I've already created) can't be seen on the old portal.

But that isn't the issue -
Now that I've got my system running online I would like to create an image of it (I assume that it's called 'capture' in Azure) so that I will be able to clone it easily and run tests.

My VM run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the new Azure portal,
I've tried to find any references on how to do it but couldn't... maybe the feature is missing on the new portal ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically  the problem is in two types of virtual machines in Azure - classic ones based on Cloud Service) and new ones based on Resource Group. It is possible to migrate from classic VM to new VM and no way back.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-migration-classic-resource-manager-deep-dive/

I may just advise you to recreate your VM in classic mode.